# Hibernate + Spring MVC: external objects library

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have two different applications (site + some cron utility) that are using the same database objects. I moved them into separate library, and in the applications I left only hibernate.configuration files.

Now, the problem is that I have some email notification service that uses JavaMailSender and it have properties defined in spring configuration file:

```
<bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
        <property name="host" value="mail.xxx.com" />
        <property name="username" value="xxx" />
        <property name="password" value="xxx" />
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">*</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="notificationsService" class="de.crm.NotificationsService">
        <property name="sender" ref="mailSender" />
        <property name="properties" ref="notificationsServiceProperties" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="notificationsServiceProperties" class="de.crm.objects.properties.NotificationsServiceProperties">
        <property name="name" value="xxx" />
        <property name="email" value="xxx" />
    </bean>
```

So the main problem here that it can't see de.crm.objects.properties.NotificationsServiceProperties class because it is defined in external library and the project fails at export.

Is there any way to leave the properties class in external library and fix it?
Thank you

UPD#1: Is it possible to use objects from external library Spring's with @Autowired annotation?

Comment: Is the external jar added to the build path or is the external jar placed in the classpath , from where it can be read ?

Comment: I have added the external jar as an external library in Buildpath settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> So the main problem here that it can't see de.crm.objects.properties.NotificationsServiceProperties class because
> ```
>
> it is defined in external library and the project fails at export.

Spring cannot recognize a class/library if it is not included in the project's classpath. So you need to ensure that your library either internal or external, is included in classpath.

> ```
> UPD#1: Is it possible to use objects from external library Spring's with @Autowired annotation?
> ```

@Autowired only supplies those objects which are present in spring context. If a class is outside spring context, even if it is included in classpath, it will not be recognized by @Autowired.

**EDIT**

First, add the class (for example, `foo.Bar`) to your classpath.

Second, add a new bean definition in your spring configuration xml:

```
<bean class="foo.Bar"></bean>
```

Now, you can access this object using @Autowired:

```
public class SomeOtherClassInSpringContext {
    @Autowired
    Bar myBar;
}
```

P.S. If you haven't already done so, you also need to apply `<context:annotation-config/>` and `<context:component-scan base-package="path.to.your.classes"/>` in order to tell spring that you have configured some of your classes with annotations.

For more information, refer to [Spring docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/).

Comment: So is there any way to add an external object to Spring context?

Comment: Ahhh, ok, I did it already:) I solved the problem. All you need to do is to add an external jar to WEB-INF/lib/ directory. And you don't have to add this jar as external library in project's settings. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, you should put the JAR containing your external classes on your application's classpath. Then your class will be visible by Spring's context.
It's what we do for example to configure a datasource.
In a general manner, Spring can handle every class on your classpath...

Comment: What do you mean? Add this jar as external library? I already did it, doesn't help